# get asynchronous value from firebase firestore reference

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the name value from this promise from firebase firestore database:

(as for information I have a places colection that have a place containing a name and a ownerReference that references an owner document containing a name only.)

```
var names: any = [];
this.props.places.snapshot.docs.forEach((doc : any) => {
  const place = doc.data()
  place.ownerReference.get().then((snap : any) => {
    name.push(snap.data().name);
    console.log(names);
  })
});
console.log(names);
```

the first console log return the desired data, the last one returns an empty object, I know this is happening because of the asynchronous nature of a promise , but how can I get the desired value assigned to this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect all the promises from each `get()` into an array, then use Promise.all() to wait until they are all done.  Iterate the resulting snapshots in the callback after that.

```
const promises = []
this.props.places.snapshot.docs.forEach((doc : any) => {
    const place = doc.data()
    promises.push(place.ownerReference.get())
})

Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots => {
    const names = []
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        names.push(snapshot.data().name)
    })
    console.log(names);  // this prints what you want
})
```

Comment: Way easier with Array.map

Comment: @JonasW. Sure, but the OP didn't use it, so I didn't want to conflate the issue.

Comment: got this erro: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}' o this line `names.push(snapshot.data().name)`

Comment: Nevermind, is was a typescript issue (did not specify the types on snapshots), sothis answer is no doubt correct, thanks a lot

Comment: @GustavoFreire Yep exactly typescript d.ts nice catch